# Installing wordpress on WAMP gives empty tables only

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wampserver

I’m installing wordpress on WAMP and i have problem.
nstallation is not completed properly and all database tables are empty ( wp_users are empty ). Not sure how it manages to create tables but not enter data. after last step of wordpress install, page is not loaded completely, it doesn’t say “WP installed and you can now login". Cannot login(login error).  I tried creating new user for database with all privileges and using these details for installation. Still doesn’t work. All database tables are empty, something is preventing entering sample data and I’m not sure what this could be.
Wamp server is working ok! (apache and mysql run and work).

Comment: Can you add something manually to any of these tables? Via phpMyAdmin for example.

Comment: Yes, its updating. But this not help

Answer (score 1):

Check your `php error log` and `apache error log`. The issue is probably that the script is timing out somewhere in the database creation and load step.

If so try increasing the `max_execution_time` in your php.ini.
Edit the php,ini using the wampmanager menu system to ensure you are editing the correct file.

Try changing it temporarily to a larger number like

```
max_execution_time = 240
```

But change it back to something sensible like 30 or 60 once the install has completed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I resolved incrementing max_execution_time until 240.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on Google and it turns out more people are having these problems on WAMP and in most cases they are adviced to check if their PHP version isn't too low - i'd suggest doing the same, so:

- Make sure your A-M-P environment meets the Wordpress requirements (A-M-P versions and required mods).
- Make sure the user in database you are passing credencials for in installation steps have all required privileges (and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`).

P.S. Some person asked yesterday similar question on official WordPress forums - there is no answer so far, but following this topic won't hurt:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/installing-wordpress-on-wamp-gives-empty-tables-only